# Java setRequestHeader in Python

Tags: java, python, http-headers

What is the equivalent of this java statement in python?

```
post.setRequestHeader("Cookie", jSessionID);
```

I'm very confused as to whether this is really a cookie or just POST data with a key of 'Cookie'

I have urllib2 and cookielib imported, and am confused.

I'm also trying to send a file along with the url request, but that is another topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
sock = httplib.HTTPConnection('server.com', 80)
data = "op=a_login_attempt"
headers = { "Host":"server.com",
            "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF=8",
            "Referer":"server2.com",
            "Cookie":"session=12345678",}
sock.request("POST", '/login.php', data, headers)
```

As you can see "Cookie" is just a key and value in the `headers`, which get sent along with the `data` using the `request()` method. Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [pycurl](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2004-05/0214.html)